# How to pass JSON body in HTTP Put in JAVA

Tags: java, http, http-put

Can someone explain me how to pass JSON parameter in request body.
I am using HttpURLConnection to create the connection, as below:

```
URL uri = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try{
        uri = new URL(url); //URL is hardcoded as of now
        con = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod(type); //type: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setConnectTimeout(60000); //60 secs
        con.setReadTimeout(60000); //60 secs
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
        con.setRequestProperty("Postman-Token", "448b7c42-61f1-4373-8a7d-80a0a4610b99");

        JSONObject reqBody = new JSONObject();
        reqBody.put("state", "4");
        System.out.println(reqBody);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(reqBody.toString());
         if( reqBody != null){  
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream out = new  DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
```

How can I put set the req body here?

Comment: use `setEntity` method (I found a prettry good example here: https://www.javaquery.com/2016/01/apache-httpput-example.html)

Comment: This is good, but how can I add the Authorization here, as basic auth?

Comment: The sample has a section with `httpPut.addHeader("Authorization", "value");` just replace the value where the valu is `user/password` encoded in base-64 format (thank you MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme)

Comment: You definitively don't want to send "Accept-Encoding: application/json".

Answer (score 2):

For specifying the body of your request:

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
wr.write(reqBody.toString());
wr.flush()
```